# Is there a safe way to use one Gitlab project inside of another?

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

So, suppose you have several projects with the same dependency script, but as it stands you currently have that same script in different projects with minor changes. For example suppose you have the following:

projectA/alpha.sh

```
echo "The first letter of alphabet is A"
```

projectB/alpha.sh

```
echo "The second letter of alphabet is B"
```

Obviously, this is a lot of repeated code, and there should be a way to create one script, that each project can pull from, such as:

projectUtility/alpha.sh

```
echo "The {order} letter of alphabet is {givenLetter}"
```

How exactly would you import something like this either in/outside the Gitlab pipeline of another project, so you can use it, without making it an actual part of that code base? The only way that comes to mind is cloning the project into your code base while within the pipeline, like:

```
stages:
  - pullScript

pullScript:
  stage: pullScript
  script:
    - git clone git@gitlab.com:projectUtility.git
    - cd projectUtility
    - bash alpha.sh "first" "B"
    - cd ..
    - rm -r projectUtility
```

However, this does not work. I keep getting the following errors:

```
$ git clone git@gitlab.com:projectUtility.git
Cloning into 'projectUtility'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

OR

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.com/projectUtility.git
Cloning into 'projectUtility'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: IMO your method is fine. You could also use a `git submodule`,

Comment: Do you think you could provide an example of the `git submodule` method?